# Can I share variables in a catch call in Prolog?

Tags: algorithm, prolog

I'm developing a task scheduler in Prolog. First of all let me show you a simplified version of my code. It goes like this:

```
handle_activable(As) :-
    reset_flags,
    findall(A,catch(activable(A),Exception,flag(marked_activable,A)),As),
    activate_all(As).
```

There are two versions of `activable/1` but the most relevant one is (again simplified):

```
activable(T) :-
    task(T),        /* T is a task */
    inactive(T),    /* The task is currently inactive */
    (\+checked(T) ->
        mark_checked(T),
        !,
        /* 
           Here would go the set of conditions 
           and  statements to determine if task T 
           is activable or not. They may internally 
           call activable/1.
        */
        asserta(flag(marked_activable,T))
    ;   
        /* 
           This task was already checked and the 
           result is stored in flag(marked_activable,T) 
           fact. 
        */
        throw(exception(already_checked,T))
    ).
```

The thing is that, within the "set-of-conditions-check",`activable/1` might be indirectly called. That's why I need to use `checked/1`, in order to avoid unwanted loops.
I guessed the way I use `findall/3` was okay, but since `As` is always instantiated as the empty list `[]` I'm starting to think there's something wrong with it.

The first thing I would like to ask you is the catch(...) call. Is it correct? I mean, if during an `activable/1` call, the program throws an exception because the task has been already checked, would `A` still be instantiated (so that I can use it in `flag(marked_activable,A)`)? If not, do you know any workaround for that?

The second thing I would like to ask you is about the correctness of my algorithm. I've been working on this for so long now and I did my best to have an efficient, robust and reliable code. The real hard thing is within the set-of-conditions check, where task's relations play a great role and create complex constrains. Do you think the way of "finding activable tasks" is a good one?

Comment: Unwanted loops may appear because I check relations between tasks. They can be "dependency" or "exclusivity" relations, and in both cases I check if those relations are activables/not activables.

Comment: Rather than leave comments on your own question you should just edit the question and incorporate the information.

Comment: Ok! Thanks for the advice, I'll keep that in mind from now on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the built-in `catch/3` predicate, the correct way for passing information is through the `Catcher` term.

```
catch(:Goal, +Catcher, :Recover)
```

According to SWI-Prolog doc, the `Goal` is the innermost goal for which `Catcher` unifies with the argument of `throw/1`, all choice points generated by `Goal` **are cut** and the system backtracks to the start of `catch/3` while preserving the thrown exception term.
Thus, having a rule like:

```
generate(info1).
generate(info2).
generate(info3).
generate(info4).
rule(D) :-
    generate(D),
    ...
    throw(error_info(D)).
```

The result of catching this rule would be something like that:

```
?- catch(rule(D), Exception, write(Exception)).
error_info(info1).
Exception = error_info(info1).

?- catch(rule(_), error_info(E), write(E)).
info1.
E = info1.
```